# How to use LDAP on window azure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, active-directory, adfs

Am new to ADFS and LDAP, our project is mixed of technology mongoDb, nodeJS and rails. we are planning on deploying mongodb, Nodejs or Rails on Windows Azure, as LDAP is been used for active directory on ruby.how LDAP used in window azure. is there any performance change in using **ADFS in ruby** compare to **LDAP in ruby**. if yes, how can i implement **ADFS on RUBY**

Is anyone know how its possible. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your LDAP server going to stay on-premises? Just to be clear, ADFS is not equivalent to LDAP. ADFS is a "Security Token Service" (STS). LDAP is a Directory.

Since you mention ADFS, presumably your apps will authenticate users on (on-premises) Active Directory. ADFS can only authenticate users on AD, not on arbitrary directories.

To connect your node.js and ruby app to ADFS you would need to implement either WS-Federation or SAML Protocol. These are the 2 protocols supported by ADFS. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359114.aspx).

Alternatively, you can implement your own STS and connect it with whatever you want (ADFS or LDAP). If you do this, then you have more control on what kind of protocols to implement in your app (e.g. OAuth2 or something else). It seems there are more libraries you can leverage compared to WS-Fed / SAML.

There are many open source STSs you can look at. IdentityServer is one of them, and people have successfully built solutions on it. You will have to host this yourself.

Another alternative is to rely on a 3rd party service like [Auth0](http://www.auth0.com) (which is available on the Windows Azure store). (**Disclaimer**: this is a product I'm working on).

Comment: Pace, really thank you. i have planned to use client libraries provided for nodejs, ruby and mongo in window azure to deploy. But still i don't have exact idea for ADFS for nodejs, ror and mongoDb in window azure.can you suggest an idea.

Comment: ADFS is a server. There are no specific libraries for node, mongo or RoR. You would have to implement the protocols that ADFS supports.